# Accessibility — click a link/button by typing its text

Tags: keyboard, mouse, accessibility, mouse-keys, voice-control

Background: Voice Control lets you click links by just saying “Click <link/button name>”.

Question: How would I do this by typing instead of speaking? (Siri has a “Type to Siri” option, but Voice Control does not).  Is there really no accessibility option for letting the user type the text of the button they want to click?

What I’ve tried: I tried Switch Control, but it scans for links instead of letting you jump to ones matching a given text.  I’ve also tried Cmd+F in Safari to highlight links, but nothing I’ve found lets me click the highlighted link without using the mouse.  I’ve been using Mouse Keys to navigate instead, albeit slowly.

Answer (score 0):

In Safari you can use <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>⇨Tab</kbd> to move through clickable controls/links on a webpage. Use <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>⇨Tab</kbd> move backward through the page. Then use the <kbd>⏎ Return</kbd> key to open the link. You can make it a bit easier by turning on "Press tab to highlight each item on a webpage" in *Safari → Preferences → Advanced*. That will remove the need to use the <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> key, so just use <kbd>⇨Tab</kbd> and <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>⇨Tab</kbd>.